# FQL for getting facebook user ids does not return "paging" key in response

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, paging, facebook-fql

Hi i want to get list of my fabebook friend ids with paging of 100 users.
The problem is that if i set hte FQL to

```
        NSString *fqlString = @"SELECT uid FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) LIMIT 300";
```

It returns me as expected the only first 300 users in the table with out any reference to next page.

```
Result: {
data =     (
            {
        uid = 1519xxx;
    },
            {
        uid = 9806xxx;
    }

....
);

}
```

if i request friends with `[FBRequest requestForMyFriends]` it returns me all of my friends and additionaly a paging key with the url object for next page.

The question is how can i tell with FQL to give me lists of 100 users with paging to next 100 users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Graph API returns paging links; FQL does not. So you’d have to do that yourself, by making another query including an OFFSET parameter.

Comment: how do you mean by making another request including Offset?

Comment: `SELECT … FROM … WHERE … LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10`

Comment: i think i have got point you mean i need to calculate the number of total friends and totally make n/offset requests to server

Comment: is it possible to control the size of pages in grapapi?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/, section “Paging”. Please start reading docs before asking.

Comment: BTW from now on wards graph api will return only your friends that are your current app users. It will not return all of ur friends.