# Paging in Facebook FQL

Tags: facebook, pagination, facebook-fql

I am trying to get all the chat conversations of an user. I get the access token and directly query the facebook tables(no graph api,just plain FQL).[FQL Guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/fql/)

This is the query I am using

> select body,thread_id from message where thread_id in 
>       (select thread_id in thread where folder_id=0 or folderid=1)

I am not getting the entire result though. I have tried Offset and Limit but not sure till what condition I should iterate this(How do I find the end??).

Also how to use since and until in FQL?? 
something like 
**`select thread_id from thread where folder_id=0 since =UNIXTIMESTAMP`** (this doesnt work!!!). How do I get this going?

Comment: possible duplicate of [FQL for getting facebook user ids does not return "paging" key in response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12931868/fql-for-getting-facebook-user-ids-does-not-return-paging-key-in-response)

Answer (score 2):

You could try using the `created_time` field of the [message table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/message) to limit the requests by time and control limiting results for each request.

For all the threads between `16/8/2011 00:00` and `16/8/2011 23:59` (my birthday) :

```
SELECT body,thread_id FROM message WHERE thread_id IN  
  (SELECT thread_id FROM thread WHERE folder_id=0 OR folder_id=1)  
AND created_time > 1313452800 AND created_time < 1313539140`
```

It would be better for performance on your end if you control the pagination... Through the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=select%20body%2Cthread_id%20from%20message%20where%20thread_id%20in%20%28select%20thread_id%20from%20thread%20where%20folder_id%3D0%20or%20folder_id%3D1%29%0A%0A), I was able to get +-750 threads, but I have no idea what (if any) limits apply. I think it would be safe to say that there would be a limit.

Comment: Though I request by time, it doesn't give up exact results. I tried to get my chats for yesterday.(It wouldn't be more than 50 messages).It doesn't retrieve all. For example,it missed out the first 5-6 conversations. Any idea ? As far as I know, there is no way to get the exact number of data, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Got it bro, it works with a limit. I guess if there is no limit specified, it takes up some default value!! Used this  SELECT body,thread_id FROM message WHERE thread_id IN  
  (SELECT thread_id FROM thread WHERE folder_id=0 OR folder_id=1)  
AND created_time > 1362182400 AND created_time < 1362376740 limit 500

Comment: You should add param LIMIT, otherwise it will run un-correct.